# Stop method execution at run time via reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection

I have this idea of an android library I want to write. I need to be able to annotate a method; At run time a check for connectivity will be done. If this condition is true the method should continue; if it's false then the method should be terminated.

I'm wondering if this can be accomplished via reflection or some other means. I saw that there are programs that modify code at run time so I was thinking I would have to put "inject" a return statement at the beginning of the method. However I should be able to restore the method to its original statement even if I injected a return statement before it's execution because if internet were enabled and the method is called again then it should be executed. Not sure if I am talking gibberish but nevertheless, any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check out AspectJ, it might be what you might be looking for.

Comment: Would throwing an exception and catching it stop the annotated method's execution ?

Comment: I'm not sure about that, i'm in the learning phase as well. But there is something in there for exceptions if I am not mistaken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using AspectJ to accomplish my task. In order to check intercept method execution I combined annotations with advices. So I wrote an annotation. Used a pointcut to detect all methods that are annotated; which would then become join points and then an around advice is triggered by the pointcut where the method/join point only proceeds if my condition was met.